# jQuery Dropdown - Find out what was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="">Deutsch</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Denmark</a></li>
```

I want to find out with jQuery what point of the dropdown menu was clicked.

I tried it so:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="" id="changeLanguage" requestLanguage="german">Deutsch</a></li>
   <li><a href="" id="changeLanguage" requestLanguage="denmark">Denmark</a></li>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#changeLanguage").click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("requestLanguage"));
});
```

But only the first dropdown point (german) calls the jQuery Event. Denmark has no function.

How I can realize it?

Comment: `id`s must be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: `requestLanguage` should be `data-requestLanguage` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `id` can only be used once on the page. Change them to a `class` like so:

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="" class="changeLanguage" requestLanguage="german">Deutsch</a></li>
     <li><a href="" class="changeLanguage" requestLanguage="denmark">Denmark</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(".changeLanguage").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   alert($(this).attr("requestLanguage"));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/spdb0uLh/)